Need help with a variation of the domino tiling problem
There are two questions I need some help with. They both involve a ‘honeycomb strip’ (which is just a hexagonal tessellation of two rows), ‘worker bees’ (which take up two hexagons), and larvae (which take up one hexagon).

How can we count the number of ways there are for worker bees and larvae to arrange themselves in an n-cell honeycomb strip? Explain.

Superstitious worker bees will only face up-right. How many ways are there for superstitious worker bees and larvae to arrange themselves in an n-cell honeycomb strip? Why?


attached is a screenshot of the question for clarity
This kind of reminded me of that famous domino tiling problem, so it appears that we need to use induction. I tried to build to recurrences: when n = 2k (An) and when n = 2k+1 (Bn).
And I got something like
An = Bn-1 + An-1 + An-2 + Bn-2 , and
Bn = An + Bn-1 + An-1 + Bn-2 ,
but apparently that’s not right
Thank you to any answers in advanced!

In case 1, do we care about the direction in which the bees are looking?

Question 1
Let's introduce some indexing of cells as follows:

Notice the fact, that "worker bees" always occupy only cells that indicies do not differ by more than $2$.
Let's define $f(n)$ to be number of demanded arrangements for $n$-cell grid. Now we can focus on investigating reccurence relation. We have to go through some cases.
Case 1: Last cell contains larva.
Remaining $n - 1$ cells form correct arrangement, so we have $\boxed{f(n- 1)}$ possibilities for that.
Case 2: "Worker bee" occupies cells $n$ and $n-1$.
Remaining $n - 2$ cells form correct arrangement, so we have $\boxed{f(n- 2)}$ possibilities for that.
Case 3: "Worker bee" occupies cells $n$ and $n - 2$, cell $n-1$ contains larva.
Remaining $n - 3$ cells form correct arrangement, so we have $\boxed{f(n- 3)}$ possibilities for that.
Case 4: "Worker bee" occupies cells $n$ and $n - 2$, cell $n-1$ contains another "worker bee".
The only possibility for that is when this another "worker bee" occupies cells $n-1$ and $n-3$. Therefore remaining $n - 4$ cells form correct arrangement, so we have $\boxed{f(n- 4)}$ possibilities for that.
Those cases are the only possible, thus we have our recursion defined as follows:
$$
f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3) + f(n -4)
$$
We can calculate by hand:
$$
f(1) = 1 \quad f(2) = 2 \quad f(3) = 4 \quad f(4) = 8
$$
And then we can arrange all the result in table and try to calculate the consequtive values of $f(n)$ manually by adding $4$ previuous values.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 15 & 29 & \dots\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Question 2
You can see that in this case each pair of "top-right" connected cells either contains a "worker bee" or larvae. Since there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ such pairs, thus we have $2^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$ such arrangements.
